# For Loop in Visual Studio 2019(Visual Basic) Not Doing what I expect it to do

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I'm not the best with for loops, but as I understand the loop should continue to run for as many characters in "StupidString". In the code below, the way I think it should run and the way it is running is completely different. The way I see it the If statement("A") should run 3 times. The way it is running is that the If statement("A") only runs once. The TextBox1.Text shows 5. If someone can show me what I am missing I would appreciate it. I am sure it is something stupid. Thanks

```
    Dim len As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim key As String
    Dim StupidString As String = "ACCAA"


    len = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Len(StupidString)

    For i = 1 To len
        key = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Mid(StupidString, i, 1)
        TextBox1.Text = key

        If key = "A" Then
            My.Computer.Audio.Play("Local audio file")
        ElseIf key = "B" Then
            My.Computer.Audio.Play("Local audio file")
        End If

    Next
```

Comment: I ran this code and it worked as expected.  "A" ran 3 times, and I ended up with an "A" in my textbox.

Comment: but what should you intended functioning be?

Comment: `For Each c As Char In StupidString  Console.WriteLine(c.Equals("A"c)) Next`. This: `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Len` is `StupidString.Length()`, this: `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Mid()` is `StupidString.SubString()`. You probably don't want/need to use code coming from another millennium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`My.Computer.Audio.Play`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/computer-resources/playing-sounds) starts playing the sound in the background and does not wait for it to finish.
If a sound is already playing, it stops it and starts the new one.

Because your `For` loop executes very fast, it starts the `A` sound three times almost simultaneously. The net result is that you hear it playing once (the last scheduled time).

If you want to play the sound three times, specify the [second parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.audio.play?view=netframework-4.8#Microsoft_VisualBasic_Devices_Audio_Play_System_String_Microsoft_VisualBasic_AudioPlayMode_):

```vb
My.Computer.Audio.Play("Local audio file", AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
```

Comment: Good catch.  I commented out the Audio lines to test the correctness of the loop, and never considered the audio playing async.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the forums,  @lriehlou812!

I took the liberty of cleaning things up for you a little -- it will help you to advance to new levels. :-)

The most important thing to take from your code is this: ALMOST everything in VB is base 0 (meaning the first position of a string is position "0". `Mid()` however is Base 1. [(See more information here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/zero-based-vs-one-based-string-access). I didn't totally analyze your code to prove that out but that should help you figure your problem out.

Also -- I didn't "test" my code but it should work.

Happy coding. Hope this helps.

```
Sub TestLoop()
    Dim StupidString As String = "ACCAA"
    For i = 0 To StupidString.Length - 1
        Select Case StupidString(i)
            Case "A"
                My.Computer.Audio.Play("Local audio file")
            Case "B"
                My.Computer.Audio.Play("Local audio file")
            Case "C"
                'do nothing?
        End Select
        TextBox1.Text = StupidString(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The OP is correctly using `Len` and `Mid` that are one-based. Rewriting it to `.Length` and `.Substring` is a stylistic choice that does not affect correctness of the code.

Comment: I don't disagree. I just thought that I'd bring it to the OP's attention in that if they are coming from another base one language or are new to coding that it's easy to think in base 1. JMHO